# Site PHP não lê caracteres especiais

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin, utf-8

O Site que me mandaram (Sou estagiário) está com problemas pois não está lendo os caracteres especiais. Já observei o famoso `charset UTF-8`, porém quando fui olhar o bando de dados, a colação está `"latin1_swedish_ci"`.

Este pode ser o motivo ? Ouvi dizer que se alterar ele não volta a ler, tem que reescrever tudo, é verdade ?

Comment: O padrão de caracteres do site deve ser o mesmo do banco de dados caso não você continuará a ter problemas com a acentuação mas existem alguns comandos para adequar ao caractere e também poderá tratar a saída do caractere na conexão do banco de dados diga qual é o charset do seu html/php

Answer (score -2):

Na criação do banco você setou para UTF8 ou deixou o padrão? Faz um teste e realiza essa alteração no banco (localhost e faz um backup pfv kk)

***ALTER DATABASE nomeBD CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;***

Ou cria um banco novamente como utf8 e faz a importação. Você pode também, se preferir é claro, apenas fazer o tratamento da acentuação na saída.

Answer (score -2):

O *charset* que você verificou é na classe de instanciação da conexão?

Dá uma verificada, tem que estar algo parecido com o código abaixo:

```
$con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=forum;**charset=utf8**", "root", "root");
```

Comment: Como vc chegou a conclusão que ele usa PDO na conexão?!